# Call a class in file B from file A and then reference file B variables in file A

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two .py files. The first contains a class. The second imports that class and it's function, then attempts to reference variables within that function locally as so:

File B:

```
class master_test():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func_one(self, var1, var2, var3):
        if var1 == 1:
            print('first')
        else:
            print('second')
        if var2 == 2:
            print('first')
        else:
            print('second')
        if var3 == 3:
            print('first')
        else:
            print('second')
        return var1, var2, var3
```

File A:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('G:\Python36\Test\Folder_1')
from Test1 import *

test_var = master_test()
test_var.func_one(6,7,8)

temp = var1
print(temp)
```

However, when I run file A, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python36/Test/Master.py", line 8, in <module>
    temp = var1
NameError: name 'var1' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't define `var1` anywhere.

Comment: `var1` is a local variable in the function, you can't access it outside.

Comment: i need to be able to import these variables into File A somehow...

Comment: `func_one` returns the values; why aren't you writing something like `temp, _, _ = test_var.func_one(6,7,8)`?

Comment: `return` returns objects, not variables. `return var1, var2, var3` doesn't mean the caller has `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` variables now.

Comment: The only reason to *have* a variable is to access the value it is bound to, and `func_one` already provides that.

Answer (score 3):

`var1` is a local variable, you can't access it outside the function.

But it returns it, so you can assign the result.

```
x, y, z = test_var.func_one(6, 7, 8)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

var1 is not a module-level variable in Test1.py. It belongs to a function `func_one` of a class `master_test`. A class is not an object, a class is a template to create objects. You could have multiple `master_test` objects.

Imagine you had this code:

```py
from Test1 import master_test

test_var1 = master_test()
test_var2 = master_test()

test_var1.func_one(6,7,8)
test_var2.func_one(2,3,4)
```

Now if you wanted to reference var1, which one do you even want? The one from test_var1 or from test_var2? You need to re-think how you're passing around data. The correct way to pass data back from functions is to use a `return` statement.

```py
temp, _, _ = test_var1.func_one(6, 7, 8)
```

This will set temp equal to var1, which is 6.